# Cannot import date values in SharePoint list using SSIS

Tags: 2013, business-intelligence

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and SSIS-Sql server 2008 r2. Excel is a data source and Sharepoint list is the destination.I have simple transformations and the data is copied to List. I can see all column values except Date values, these columns are blank in sharepoint list. I tried single text and Date type in SharePoint list but still i cannot see date values in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the format in excel to 2016-1-1 helped in importing the date values.